# JavaFx Tableview, how to add listener and overwrite updateItem in the same factory

Tags: java, javafx

i am currently working on a small learning-project with a TableView Element. I am changeing the background colors of each row according to its content like that:

```
TableView.setRowFactory((row) -> new TableRow<Person>() {

@Override
public void updateItem(Person person, boolean empty) {
    super.updateItem(person, empty);

    switch (person.getPersonStatus()) {
      case ST:
        setStyle("-fx-control-inner-background: " + StatusColor.B_LIGHT.getMyColorValue() + "; -fx-text-fill: #fff;");
        break;
      case CD:
        setStyle("-fx-control-inner-background: " + StatusColor.D_LIGHT.getMyColorValue() + "; -fx-text-fill: #fff;");
        break;
    }
}
```

i additionally like to get a reference of the object in that row when i doubleclick on the row. I use this code for that:

```
TableView.setRowFactory((row) -> {
  TableRow<Person> row = new TableRow<>();
  row.setOnMouseClicked(event -> {
    if (event.getClickCount() == 2 && (!row.isEmpty())) {
      Person rowData = row.getItem();
      System.out.println(rowData);
    }
  });
  return row;
});
```

but that doesn't work together (i assume because i am assigning two factorys which override each other). Can somebody please help me out to combine both code examples into a working one? How is it possible to override a function (updateItem) in a factory and attach a listener at the same time?

best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the listener to the `TableRow` you create in the first code block:

```
TableView.setRowFactory((tv) -> {
    TableRow<Row> row = new TableRow<Person>() {

        @Override
        public void updateItem(Person person, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(person, empty);

            switch (person.getPersonStatus()) {
              case ST:
                setStyle("-fx-control-inner-background: " + StatusColor.B_LIGHT.getMyColorValue() + "; -fx-text-fill: #fff;");
                break;
              case CD:
                setStyle("-fx-control-inner-background: " + StatusColor.D_LIGHT.getMyColorValue() + "; -fx-text-fill: #fff;");
                break;
            }
        }
    };
    row.setOnMouseClicked(event -> {
        if (event.getClickCount() == 2 && (!row.isEmpty())) {
          Person rowData = row.getItem();
          System.out.println(rowData);
        }
    });
    return row;
});
```